# Out to set audio file in AudioConfig function from Azure cognitive services

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin.forms, speech-recognition

I would like to load an audio wav file in My Xamarin forms project.

The audio file is in SpeechApp=>Data=>audio.wav

I am using the Azure AudioConfig function like this:

```
var taskCompleteionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
            var config = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription("xxx", "xx");

       var transcriptionStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();


      // Replace the language with your language in BCP-47 format, e.g., en-US.
      var language = "fr-FR";
      config.SpeechRecognitionLanguage = language;
      config.OutputFormat = OutputFormat.Detailed;

using (var audioInput = AudioConfig.FromWavFileInput("SpeechApp.Data.audio.wav"))
        {
            using (var recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(config, audioInput))
            {


                // Stops recognition.  
                await recognizer.StopContinuousRecognitionAsync();
            }
        }
```

But It is not working and I have this error : `System.DllNotFoundException: Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.dll`

My error comes from this lines : `var config = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription()`

I was inspired from this web site :[click here](https://dejanstojanovic.net/aspnet/2019/january/mp3-to-text-using-azure-cognitive-services/)

Thanks for your help

Comment: is the file an embedded resource, an asset, a file, etc?

Comment: @Jason   yes it is  but I have the same result

Comment: That was not a yes or no question.  `FromWavFileInput` expects a file path, and you appear to be passing it a resource name.

Comment: @Jason   it is a file in my project xamarin  App

Comment: @Jason How Can I give the path of my file while it is in the App (SpeechApp=>Data=>audio.wav)?

Comment: "SpeechApp/Data/audio.wav"

Comment: @Jason this is not working I have the same error : System.DllNotFoundException: Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.dll

Comment: That is a **COMPLETELY DIFFERENT ERROR** than you included in your question.  Your question says "But it cannot find the audio file."  How can we help you when you can't even accurately describe your problem?

Comment: @Jason I have always get the same error when the file was not found

Comment: @Jason I am sorry as my question was not clear

Comment: @Jason my error comes from  SpeechConfig.FromSubscription() like in the link I gave

Comment: @Jason I have added some code

Answer (score -1):

Could you please try something like below:

```
using (var audioInput = AudioConfig.FromWavFileInput(@"SpeechApp.Data.audio.wav"))
            {
                using (var recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(config, audioInput))
                {

}
```

You can refer [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/tree/master/samples) link for more samples in different languages.

Hope it helps.

Comment: hanks but this is not working , I have the same error : System.DllNotFoundException: Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.dll

Comment: Have you tried to add this dll? When you do that, do you still have this error?